# Lifting of matrix units

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, k-theory

My question is originally about the analysis of extensions of $M_n$ by $K(H)$,"$K$-theory for operator algebras"- Blackadar, Exmaple $15.4.1.(b).$
We examine extensions of $M_n$ by $K(H)$, so that we need to look at the Busby invariant, i.e. homomorphism $\tau: M_n\to Q(H)$, where $Q$ denotes the Clakin algebra. 
Let $\{\bar{e_{ij}}\}$ be the matrix units in $\tau(M_n)$.
First lift $\{\bar{e_{ii}}\}$ to orthogonal projections $p_{ii}$ in $B(H)$.
Then we get (by some process) $\{e_{ij}\}$ lifted set of matrix units, so that we have $\bar{\tau}:M_n\to B(H)$ s.t. $\pi\circ \bar{\tau}=\tau$, where $\pi$ denotes the canonical quotient map.
$\bar{\tau}$ is not necessarily unital, but $p=\sum e_{ii}$ is a projection of finite co-dimension $k$, i.e. $(1-p)B(H)(1-p)\cong M_k(\Bbb{C})$. This part is not clear to me, why does $p$ must have a finite co-dimension?

Thank you for any help

Comment: Because the image of $p$ in the Calkin algebra is the unit. In particular, $p$ is a Fredholm operator.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Just to be sure: I think Blackadar does not assume that $\tau(1)=\pi(p)=1_{\Bbb{Q}}$ (he writes "even if..." but in the second paragraph he considers non-unital $\tau$).  Maybe injectivity of $\tau$ can help, but it seems to me that $\tau(1)$ can be any projection in the Calkin algebra, so not necessarily an invertible element. Do I miss something?

Comment: As you say, you need injectivity. Since $\tau$ is injective, $\sigma(\tau(1)) = \sigma(1_{M_n(\mathbb{C})})$, and so $0\notin \sigma(\tau(1))$. So $\tau(1)$ is invertible, and so $p$ is Fredholm once again.

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan Yes, this was the argument in my mind. However, I don't think it works in non-unital homomorphisms case, for example: Let $\varphi:\Bbb{C} \to M_2$ be defined by $\varphi(a)=diag(a,0)$. Then it is an injective $^*$-homomorphism but $\sigma(\varphi(1))=\sigma(diag(1,0))=\{0,1\}\neq \sigma(1_{\Bbb{C}})=1$

Comment: Yes, you are right. Let me think about this.